# Suggestion: Drag and Dropping Between PictureBoxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, drag-and-drop, picturebox

I have included 2 images so you can understand my question easier,
I could not link them directly in here as I am a new member, so I have put them in my Dropbox public folder,

**Image 1: Design View**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wca5gstd8kdsie7/designView.png?dl=0

Here you can see a Group Panel on the left,
With 6 smaller boxes nested they are all "pictureBoxes",

Then on the right is a larger picture Box, with a smaller one nested inside,

**Image 2 Application Running**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5bknooks17of1r/appView.png?dl=0

Here you can see the images loaded on the left (Please ignore the distortion of the images, this is something I will fix after)

What I need to do, is drag some images (the phrases) from the left hand side, into the circle in the right hand side, within the "segments",

Then I want to save the circle, with the new images that have been dragged on top of it (which I will do a drawToBitmap), I just want to know what is the best way for me to go about this?

Some suggestion please would be appreciated,

I can move the images on the left at the moment, but only a tiny amount as they are currently restricted to only move within their picture Box,

Comment: I suggest using the three mouse events for moving the images: MoveDown, MouseMove and MouseUp. There are many examples for this here. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750427/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-labels-within-flowlayoutpanels/27754110?s=1|2.3596#27754110),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475152/how-can-i-drag-dynamically-created-pictureboxes/24475294?s=2|1.9390#24475294)

Comment: To decide if you have hit a target segment you should create a List of GraphicsPaths (each consisting of Arc + Line +  Arc +  Line) and check if GP.IsVisible(point) is true for one. The same graphicsPath can then be used to clip drawing the image onto the target segment.

Comment: PS: Actually two Add.Arc and a CloseAllFigures will do for a Segment

Comment: @TaW Hi, thanks for your suggestion, I am currently looking into what you said, I would just like to ask, is there a specific "topic" I could search for to read about this? Also...will this "segments" be use-able like a "pictureBox"

Comment: The segments should be GraphicsPaths. This is a very useful class which can hold the geomerty of a complicated path by adding all kinds of element to it. A segment would be created by adding two  Arcs  and then closing the path. If you want to I'll post an answer that shows you a segment path routine.  When you have created a List of the segments you can use them to a) draw the circle b) check in which, if any segment the dropped element  is and c) to draw the image of the dropped box cliiped to the segment.. So the segments will not hold pixels but shapes..

Comment: Instead of using them to draw the images you could also use them to clip the picturebox' display region..

Comment: @TaW If you could , that would be really helpful! I am relativity new to coding, especially when using images I have always been messing with databases, basic GUI programs etc, though I dont want to draw the circle, would I not be able to use a pictureBox and have an image with the circle only then create the segments using the graphicPaths? Im sorry for bugging you...But you have been very helpful...How can I "upvote" you for helping?

Comment: You can't upvote until you have gained 15 reputation points but if you find my answer useful you can 'accept'  by clicking on the checkmark at its top left..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem consists of three tasks:

- Moving `Controls` (here: `PictureBoxes`) around.
- Checking to see where they have landed
- Placing them in a way that makes them join in the target area

Here are a few hints about each task:

- To move the `Controls` it is best to use the `MouseDown` to store a starting point and the `MouseMove` event to update the `Location` of the moving control. And in the `MouseUp` event you can finalize the action: Maybe process the hit, reset the control, output user messages, etc..

Note that the events belong to each control you to move, but if you map them to the same three events for all controls you can use the `sender` parameter to move the right `Control`. Much better than repeating the same code n times..

(One can even write a reusable function `makeMoveable(Control ctl)` to make any `Control` moveable; this could involve three `lambda` expressions for the three events..)

Also note that if your controls originally sit inside some container, say a `Panel` you will need to change their `Parent` to be, probably best, the `Form`; here you also will need to adapt the location by the offset of the original parent and you need to use `BringtoFront()` to make them move above all other controls on the Form..

- For hit testing you need to check if the new location is inside a segment of a circle. A segment is a more complicated shape than, say a `Rectangle`. Complicated shapes can be constructed by adding simple things to a `GraphicsPath`.

`Rectangles` also **seem** easier for hit testing since they have a `Rectangle.Contains(Point)` function. For no special reason the same function for `GraphicsPaths` goes by the name `GraphicsPath.IsVisible(Point)`.

- If you have a list of `GraphicsPaths` that make up the full circle you can use it to restrict the drawing and draw the right image directly onto the circle after using `Graphics.SetClip(segment)`.

To get you going with segments here is a function that creates a segment and paints it onto a `PictureBox` pb_target in its `Paint` event. Note that the two `Arcs` are drawn in opposite directions so that `Closing` the `Path` will not create crossing connections!

```
List<GraphicsPath> segments = new List<GraphicsPath>();


private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     PointF center = new PointF(pb_target.Width / 2f, pb_target.Height / 2f);
     float angle = 60f;
     for (int i = 0; i < 360 / angle; i++)
     {
        segments.Add(getSegment(center, pb_target.Width / 2.5f, 
                                pb_target.Width / 4f, i * angle, angle));
     }

}

GraphicsPath getSegment(PointF center, float radius, float width, 
                        float startAngle, float angle)
{
    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
    float radI = radius - width;
    RectangleF OunterBounds = 
      new RectangleF(center.X - radius, center.Y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    RectangleF InnerBounds = 
      new RectangleF(center.X - radI, center.Y - radI, 2 * radI, 2 * radI);

    gp.AddArc(OunterBounds, startAngle, angle);
    gp.AddArc(InnerBounds, startAngle + angle, -angle);
    gp.CloseFigure();

    return gp;
}

private void pb_target_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < segments.Count; i++)
    {
        GraphicsPath gp = segments[i];
        e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Gainsboro, gp);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.SlateBlue, gp);
    }

}
```

You don't need the painting code above in the final version but it will help you to fine tune the coordinates, i.e. the center and the sizes in the `getSegment` routine..

Strictly for testing here is a `MouseMove` event for the target PB:

```
private void pb_target_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < segments.Count; i++)
    {
        GraphicsPath gp = segments[i];
        if (gp.IsVisible(e.Location))
        {
            Text = "Inside segment #" + i; 
            break;
        }
        else Text = "Outside of the Circle";

    }
}
```

Note the the segments count clockwise from the left..

Comment: Thanks!
You have been really helpful, going to give this a go now,
Just looking at the code, I don't mean to sound like a nunce, but... I see you're declaring "center" but what kind of data type will that be declared as?

Im exciting to begin learning this ^_^

Comment: A `PointF` I have added it to the `Form_Load`