# Make Label To Follow Cursor While Dragging

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two DataGridView controls on my form. I want to create a label that displays information while the user is dragging from one DataGridView to the other. The label should disappear after the drag and drop event is finished.

```vb
Private Sub Datagridview1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Datagridview1.MouseDown
    Dim SourceRow As Integer
    SourceRow = Datagridview1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex
    Datagridview1.DoDragDrop(SourceRow, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    label1.Text = "....Some Info..."
    followcursor = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If followcursor = True Then
        label1.Location = e.Location
    Else
        label1.Left = 1420
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried this code, but the label starts to follow the cursor after the mouse button is released (not while dragging). Additionally, the label does not follow the cursor while the cursor is on other elements like buttons or panels. My main goal is to make the label follow the cursor while the user is dragging from one DataGridView to the other, and after the drag and drop is completed, the label should disappear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31438768/14171304 <-> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33789/Custom-Mouse-Cursors-VB-NET

Comment: @dr.null https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/36028246-7fc8-4cda-a582-de8a675a0827/drag-text-as-image?forum=winforms

Comment: @Jimi Text only? Yes.

Answer (score -1):

I think `ItemDrag`, `DragOver` and `DragDrop` events must be used here.

Comment: Someone gave me negative score without any comment. If my answer is incorrect then I would expect it explained. What is the point of such grading then? I'd say this practice of giving negative score should be prohibited by policy and moderators.